# Skype 4.3 for Linux

Tags: linux, skype

Skype 4.3 for Linux (the latest 32-bit version) had this workaround so you could keep using it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47488441/2908007

Basically, it changes the version reported to Skype servers so you could keep using it.

It worked for me for more than a year. But today I noticed I cannot login to Skype anymore (v4.3 "updated" to 8.3.0.37 or 8.34.0.9).

Does anybody experimenting problems running the old Skype client for Linux? Any hint/solution?

Thanks!

Comment: i think this is the right site to post this question, not https://stackoverflow.com/q/55502403/192798

Comment: i don't think i agree with the terms 'cheat' and 'steal' here.  smc is using official software that was obtained legally.  i think what smc is saying is that spoofing the version number used to work but no longer does, so what is the current way for 32-bit linux users to use the latest version of skype?

Comment: @fixer1234, Jayen has already explained it. It has nothing to do with cheating or stealing. Please read the hack that I mentioned, clicking on the stackoverflow link.

Comment: Thanks to Jayen for clarifying.  The way the question is worded, it reads like many we receive where people ask for help ripping off providers or developers.  :-)  It wouldn't hurt to add some clarifying context to the question.  I don't know how many of the other close voters had the same impression, or whether they had other issues with the question (I don't use Skype).  If you can clarify the question and it gets a few votes to reopen, I'll add my reopen vote.